# Laravel 4 app that caches MySQL result is serving same cached file data to all users instead of separate cached result for each user

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-4

Laravel 4 app Dtabase Caches query to File based Cashe but seems to be shared among users.

The MySQL query below loads some user permission setting for a user when they login to my system.

When I check my `/app/storage/cache/` folder it seems to only generate 1 file regardless of other users using the system.

As it seems to basically create a cache for the MySQL query of the first user to hit the system and then other users end up being served the first users cached results!

```
$permissions_query = DB::table('user_link_permissions')
    ->select(DB::raw('user_link_permissions.link_id,
        user_link_permissions.permission,
        intranet_links.entity_key'))
    ->leftJoin('intranet_links', function($leftJoin)
    {
        $leftJoin->on('user_link_permissions.link_id', '=', 'intranet_links.id');
    })
    //->where('user_link_permissions.permission', 1)
    ->where('user_link_permissions.user_id', $user_id)
    ->orderBy('parent', 'asc')
    ->remember(10, 'user_permissions')
    ->get();
```

---

The line `->remember(10, 'user_permissions')` is where I am caching my result

---

Does this sound like the correct default behavior of the DB caching mechanism and I am simply not doing it correctly?

Perhaps I am supposed to make a `cache key` with the user ID in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed the expected behaviour.

As you answered yourself, use some sort of user token in your cache key. Otherwise the cache mechanism has no way of knowing that you dont want all users to share the same query.

```
->remember(10, 'user_permission' . $user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me.  I just assumed at first since the SQL Query had a user ID in the WHERE statement that the cache would create a new cache since I assumed the different ID's in the WHERE would make the SQL different for each user.  From that perspective I still don't see how it see's it as being the same Query or whatever for the cache!  On 2nd thought I guess since I am supplying a key, it does make sense that it would serve the same cache right now! Anyways thanks!

Comment: @JasonDavis It completely ignores your query, since it sees a cache exists for that particular key. 

Alternatively, you can provide no key; in this case the key will be generated from the query and it should be different for every user. (Not sure on this on tho')

Comment: makes sense now...I should of tested it before posting here!  I do believe that prior to this I had no key but I didn't notice the issue at that stage so I didn't test the issue then so you may be right on the query being used when key is absent